Godot project completely freezes after added [Tool] script with ability to instantiate packed scene
I wanted to create a heart based health bar in Godot, where you could dynamically create an amount of hearts by changing the max health value, but when I saved the file to test it in the engine, it completely freezed Godot on build. It has freezed so hard that ending Godot from task manager takes several minutes. Code below:
[Tool]
public partial class HealthBar : Node2D
{
    [Export] PackedScene heartPrefab;
    [Export] public int maxHP { get => maxHP; set { maxHP = value; CreateHearts(); } }
    [Export] public int heartSpacing;
    Heart[] hearts;
    int currentHP;
    
    public override void _Ready()
    {
        if (hearts == null) CreateHearts();
        currentHP = maxHP;
    }
    public void CreateHearts()
    {
        foreach (Node c in GetChildren()) c.QueueFree();
        hearts = new Heart[maxHP];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxHP; i++)
        {
            hearts[i] = heartPrefab.Instantiate<Heart>();
            AddChild(hearts[i]);
            hearts[i].Position = new Vector2(i * heartSpacing, 0);
        }
    }

My theory is that maybe the maxHP has an issue because I try to override the variable, but I cannot test it, as Godot doesn't allow for further builds now.
How do I fix this? Is it possible to go inside the prefab with the script and remove it?
I would like to try problem solving, but the Engine doesn't allow for anything. I cannot even select the Godot window, and Alt-Tabbing doesn't do anything either.

Found out the issue was that the game tried to handle the heartPrefab before the user had a chance to apply it in code. It worked perfectly if i just added a "if (heartPrefab == null) return;" at the start of the CreateHearts function
